# Bootstrap carousel with thumbnail

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap carousel which has html content display sliding.

The issue here is, it works fine till 9th thumbnail, but when 11th and 12th is clicked it is sliding back to first content box instead of respective id.

here is the script used

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
              pause: true,
              interval: false
            });

            // handles the carousel thumbnails
            $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
              var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
              var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
              id = parseInt(id);
              $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
              $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
              $(this).addClass('selected');
            });

            $('#myCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
              var slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();
              var videoContent = $('.item[data-slide-number='+slideFrom+'] .embed-responsive');
              videoContent.html( videoContent.html() );
            });

            // when the carousel slides, auto update
            $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
              var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
              id = parseInt(id);
              $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
              $('[id=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
            });
```

Any help is appreciated!

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/LLafv6n3/)**

Comment: well on ten its showing ten and on eleven its showing eleven, then what is the issue?

Comment: on ten it shows zero and on eleven it shows one...

Comment: oops, i followed pre and next button..got your point.

Comment: checking..few min plz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
var parts = id_selector.split("-");
var id = parts[parts.length - 1]
```

Instead of

```
var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
```

Because your are getting only last character of the `id` which is `0` if you select `10`.

Instead i have taken last word/value after `-`.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LLafv6n3/4/)**

Comment: @ketan any lights on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148160/bootstrap-carousel-with-thumbnail-in-single-row)?

Answer (score 0):

At this line

```
var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
```

You are saying id_selector.length-1 which will always gives the last character of id_selector, so in case of `id_selector_10`you get id as 0 and same goes for id_selector_11.

If you replace it with below code it will work fine.

```
var idIndex = id_selector.lastIndexOf('-') + 1;// Get the index of character where digit starts
var id = id_selector.substr(idIndex); //Get id from that index
```

**[Updated Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/LLafv6n3/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line from

```
var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
id = parseInt(id);
```

To this: **(id_selector.length-2)**

```
var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -2);
id = parseInt(id);
```

The only thing you will have to do is, to re-number the whole set of Carousel IDs like this

```
<li> <a id="carousel-selector-00" class="selected">
<li> <a id="carousel-selector-01">
<li> <a id="carousel-selector-02">
<li> <a id="carousel-selector-03">
<li> <a id="carousel-selector-04">............
```

This should be able to solve your problem!
The length was being taken and subtracted by 1. But now, since you are subtracting 2 characters to find the ID, you will get 00 and 01 and then goes till 11 and 12.