# Bootstrap carousel with thumbnail in single row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is expanded issue of my last **[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36078255/bootstrap-carousel-with-thumbnail/)**

When the thumbnails are increased it is falling into 2nd line. how do I make it overflow(*not expecting horizontal scroll for thumbnails*) and move along with pre/next button.

```
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
              pause: true,
              interval: false
            });

            // handles the carousel thumbnails
            $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
              var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
         console.log(id_selector);
//            var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
       var parts = id_selector.split("-");
            var id = parts[parts.length - 1]
              id = parseInt(id);
              $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);

              $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
              $(this).addClass('selected');
            });

            $('#myCarousel').bind('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
              var slideFrom = $(this).find('.active').index();
              var videoContent = $('.item[data-slide-number='+slideFrom+'] .embed-responsive');
              videoContent.html( videoContent.html() );
            });

            // when the carousel slides, auto update
            $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
              var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
              id = parseInt(id);
              $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
              $('[id=carousel-selector-'+id+']').addClass('selected');
            });
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/LLafv6n3/6/)**

Comment: Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/LLafv6n3/9/

Comment: @ketan similar. but is it possible to move the thumbnail also along with slide?

Comment: you can use this kind of thing http://jsfiddle.net/rAb3V/2/ for scroll and for single line you may use `.list-inline {
    white-space: nowrap;
}`